# 'libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory' while compiling OpenCV for Arm A8

Tags: compiling, make

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I get errors while cross-compiling [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for Arm A8. Can someone help to resolve?

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target zlib
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.o
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.c.o
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.c.o
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/deflate.c.o
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.c.o
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzwrite.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inflate.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/infback.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inftrees.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inffast.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/trees.c.o
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/uncompr.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/zutil.c.o
Linking C static library ../lib/libzlib.a
[  2%] Built target zlib
Scanning dependencies of target libtiff
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_aux.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_close.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_codec.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_color.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_compress.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_dir.c.o
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_dirinfo.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_dirread.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_dirwrite.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_dumpmode.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_error.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_extension.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_fax3.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_fax3sm.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_flush.c.o
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_getimage.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_jbig.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_jpeg_12.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_jpeg.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_luv.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_lzma.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_lzw.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_next.c.o
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_ojpeg.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_open.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_packbits.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_pixarlog.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_predict.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_print.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_read.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_strip.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_swab.c.o
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_thunder.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_tile.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_version.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_warning.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_write.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_zip.c.o
[  6%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_unix.c.o
Linking CXX static library ../lib/liblibtiff.a
[  6%] Built target libtiff
Scanning dependencies of target libjpeg
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcdctmgr.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmaster.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcmaster.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdhuff.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctred.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdatasrc.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdpostct.c.o
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdatadst.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jddctmgr.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdtrans.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jfdctfst.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmerge.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmarker.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jerror.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapimin.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jccolor.c.o
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapistd.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdphuff.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jmemmgr.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcparam.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jutils.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jccoefct.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/transupp.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jchuff.c.o
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdapistd.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdcolor.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcomapi.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jfdctflt.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdsample.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jfdctint.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jquant1.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcprepct.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jquant2.c.o
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcmainct.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jctrans.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctfst.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdcoefct.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdapimin.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcphuff.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmainct.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctint.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctflt.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jmemansi.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdinput.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcsample.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcinit.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcmarker.c.o
Linking C static library ../lib/liblibjpeg.a
[ 11%] Built target libjpeg
Scanning dependencies of target libjasper
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_bs.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_stream.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jp2_dec.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_mqcod.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_t1dec.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_getopt.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_math.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jp2_cod.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_cm.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_seq.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_t2cod.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_string.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_cs.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_tmr.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_tagtree.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jp2_enc.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_debug.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_mqdec.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_mct.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_t1enc.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_t2dec.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_icc.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_util.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_iccdata.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_mqenc.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_t1cod.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_init.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_enc.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_tsfb.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_tvp.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_qmfb.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_malloc.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_version.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jas_image.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_t2enc.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjasper/CMakeFiles/libjasper.dir/jpc_dec.c.o
Linking C static library ../lib/liblibjasper.a
[ 15%] Built target libjasper
Scanning dependencies of target libpng
[ 15%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngread.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngerror.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/png.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngset.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngrtran.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngrutil.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngwutil.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngtrans.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngtest.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngwrite.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngpread.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngmem.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngrio.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngget.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngwio.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object 3rdparty/libpng/CMakeFiles/libpng.dir/pngwtran.c.o
Linking C static library ../lib/liblibpng.a
[ 17%] Built target libpng
[ 17%] Generating opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a
[ 18%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 18%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 18%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch
[ 18%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/cmdparser.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/copy.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/out.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/persistence.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/alloc.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matmul.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/datastructs.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/array.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/rand.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/drawing.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matop.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/stat.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/mathfuncs.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/gpumat.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/tables.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/dxt.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/precomp.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/opengl_interop.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/arithm.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/convert.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/algorithm.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/lapack.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
[ 20%] Built target opencv_core
[ 20%] Generating opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_ts_pch_dephelp.a
[ 20%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[ 20%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 20%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_ts_Release.gch
In file included from /home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/ts/precomp.hpp:6:0:
/home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts.hpp:306:18: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
[ 20%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_ts
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_perf.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_gtest.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_func.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/precomp.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_arrtest.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_ts.so
[ 21%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 21%] Generating opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp.a
[ 21%] Built target opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_core
[ 21%] Generating perf_precomp.hpp
[ 22%] Generating perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_core_Release.gch
In file included from /home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/perf_precomp.hpp:4:0:
/home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts.hpp:306:18: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
[ 22%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_core
[ 22%] Generating opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/OpenEXR" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gtk-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/atk-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/cairo" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pango-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pixman-1" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/freetype2" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/libpng12" is unsafe for cross-compilation
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.a
[ 22%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 22%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 22%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_highgui_Release.gch
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/OpenEXR" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gtk-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/atk-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/cairo" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pango-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pixman-1" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/freetype2" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/libpng12" is unsafe for cross-compilation
[ 22%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[ 22%] Generating opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.a
[ 22%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 22%] Generating precomp.hpp
[ 22%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_imgproc_Release.gch
[ 22%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_imgproc
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/contours.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/deriv.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/matchcontours.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/geometry.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/sumpixels.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/hough.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/shapedescr.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/undistort.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/thresh.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/pyramids.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/morph.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/smooth.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/histogram.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/corner.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/distransform.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/rotcalipers.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/linefit.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/samplers.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/subdivision2d.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/approx.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/featureselect.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/templmatch.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/filter.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/cornersubpix.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/emd.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/gabor.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/grabcut.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/convhull.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/tables.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/precomp.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/canny.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/phasecorr.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/segmentation.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/color.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/floodfill.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/accum.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/moments.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/imgwarp.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
[ 26%] Built target opencv_imgproc
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_highgui
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/OpenEXR" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gtk-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/atk-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/cairo" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pango-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pixman-1" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/freetype2" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/libpng12" is unsafe for cross-compilation
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_images.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/OpenEXR" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gtk-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/atk-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/cairo" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pango-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pixman-1" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/freetype2" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/libpng12" is unsafe for cross-compilation
[ 27%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/OpenEXR" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gtk-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/atk-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/cairo" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pango-1.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/glib-2.0" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/pixman-1" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/freetype2" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/libpng12" is unsafe for cross-compilation
In file included from /home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:56:0,
                 from /home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/home/hely/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/highgui/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:78:36: fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the `libavformat` headers. Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat53 libavformat-dev libavcodec53
```

Comment: I only needed `libavformat-dev` to get it working